# I want to assign my contacts to different FROM accounts

Tags: gmail

I manage a few forwarded email accounts from one Gmail account. I would like to assign some of my contacts to different FROM emails.

For example: I manage `steve@company1.com`, `steve@company2.com`, `steve@personal.com` from `steve@personal.com`.

When I contact `john@microsoft.com`, I would like the sender to be automatically become `steve@company1.com`, otherwise if I forget it will be `steve@personal.com`, which is not professional.

I know that Gmail does that automatically when I reply, but not when I compose. Is there a way to make it work also when I compose an email?

Comment: I'm afraid that this isn't really possible with Gmail itself. You _might_ be able to find this sort of functionality in a third-party email client (like Thunderbird), but even then I'm not 100% sure you will be able to do this.

Answer (score 3):

These are your options that I know of:

- Use Gmail's "Send Feedback..." feature to request this addition. (Don't hold your breath because it's a very specialized feature that would make Gmail more complicated for almost anyone who encountered it unless it's a Gmail lab.)
- Find or write a Chrome extension or a Greasemonkey script that modifies the Gmail UI web pages to add this feature. It will need some data lists telling it which contacts should use which "from" addresses.
- Stop forwarding all these accounts to one inbox. Instead log in to each account separately, from a separate Chrome profile per account so they can each have their own Chrome windows logged in. Name each Chrome profile after the email address. Pick a distinct Chrome theme per profile to help tell window is which.

I recommend the last approach.

Comment: I can't do the last one. Too many email addresses - one personal, 2 company, 2 for spam, 2 legacy. All of them have different web clients - horde, OWA, gmail, ... So it would be very annoying to split them. But the second solution is interesting. I will give it a try if the html/js for gmail is not ugly/anonymized. I havent used Greasemonkey yet, but it looks fun.

Comment: Cool. Do report back on how that pans out.

Comment: Of course. I will want to brag about it if I implement it.